# Time Dependent Emai alert sending to older user

Tags: email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

I have a time dependent workflow action which sends an email alert to a user present in the user lookup field. Suppose the action was scheduled 3 days ago and it is yet to be executed. Now if we change the user in the user lookup field, the email is still send to the older user.
Does the salesforce store the receiver's details statically at the time it was scheduled ? If so, then is there a workaround so that the email is send to the latest user present in the lookup field ?

Please advise. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your workflow criteria?

Comment: There is a date field(Delivery Date) on an object A. If Delivery Date is greater than or equal to TODAY then email alert is send to User in "Project Manager" field on object B.
Object A is a child object of B.

Comment: Evaluation criteria is "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria"

Comment: Somehow you have to recreate that field to be on the record of `Object A` (e.g. Process to update child records) - then WR will track change to this field and update time dependent action.